# Sharepoint 2013, FBA shows Exception, User does not exist, User not found

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, fba

Environment : SharePoint 2013 , FBA implementation, SQL server 2012.

Issue Definition : it is not allowing us to add same user name existing in resembling name of organization as shown below. it shows an exception at 2 places.

Robert.Green    robert.green@ABC    -> Successful

Robert.Green    **robert.green@ABC Codes Service -> FAIL – Exception, User does not exist,**
**User not found**

Below is code for adding users.

```
spWeb.SiteUsers.Add("i:0#.f|providername|robert.green@Codes Service", user.Email, user.UserName, string.Empty); - Exception : User does not exist

sharepointUser = spWeb.SiteUsers["i:0#.f|providername|robert.green@Codes Service"];
```

Exception : User not found

Answer (score 0):

Domain is invalid for that second user. Spaces aren't valid in that context. Replace spaces with dashes or underscores or something to avoid the issue.